# Azure search index has more than 1000 fields

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

In my application I want Azure search index which has more than 1000 fields. but no any tier supports more than 1000 fields. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to index more than 1000 fields. That said, you can vote for that feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/33234487-increase-the-number-of-fields-per-index)

Luis Cabrera | Cloud AI Platform | Microsoft